# Add values to existing json file without rewriting it

Tags: python, json

My dictionary in a JSON file looks like this:

```
{
'key1':value1
'key2':value2
}
```

I'm writing a loop where each iteration adds a new key to the dictionary in the file. For example, after one iteration the dictionary in the file looks like this:

```
{
'key1':value1
'key2':value2
'key3':value3
}
```

I want to use a method to directly append a new key into the dictionary in the file. I don't want to have to read the file in, change data and write it back out again. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: is there a reason why you want to avoid rewriting the file?

Comment: If this is a small json file and the operation will be infrequent, just rewrite the file. If the file will be huge and/or frequent read-writes, use something else e.g. a database.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather crude implementation that assumes that the file ends with } and a newline (which explains the -2):

```
with open('data.json','rb+') as f:
    f.seek(-2,2)
    f.write(b"'new_key':new_value\n}\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by finding the final closing curly brace and then using `file.seek` to go to that position. Then you can write your new values, like this:

```
with open(path, 'rb+') as f:
    s = f.read()
    index = s.rfind('}')
    f.seek(index)
    f.write(',\n[YOUR JSON HERE]\n')
    f.write(s[index:])
```

Note that if your structure is actually a list first, this will need you to use `]` instead, but otherwise this should work the same. Also note that depending on whether or not you normally use trailing commas (ie. `{a: 1, b: 13, c: 231,}`) you might want to ommit the comma I added in the first `write` command.