# Append to dictionary file in json, python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

So I have a file `python_dictionary.json` which contains a dictionary which I want to append to without having to open each time. Let's say that `python_dictionary.json` contains only:

```
{
    key1: value`
}
```

and I want to add

```
new_dictionary=
    {
        key2:value2
    }
```

Right now I am doing:

```
with open('python_dictionary.json','a') as file:
    file.write(json.dumps(new_dictionary,indent=4))
```

This creates a dictionary as:

```
{
    key1:value1
}
{
    key2:value2
}
```

which is obviously not a real dictionary.

I am aware of this: [Add values to existing json file without rewriting it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823138/add-new-key-to-dictionary-existing-in-json-file-without-rewriting-in-python)

but this deals with adding a single entry, I want to do a json.dumps

Comment: *"but this deals with adding a single entry, I want to do a json.dumps"* - I'm not sure what you mean here, the method you linked is entirely compatible with `json.dumps` and you could call it multiple times. What do you need that it doesn't do?

Comment: Just so you know that's not JSON either

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like you want to load a dictionary from json, add new key values and write it back. If that's the case, you can do this:

```
with open('python_dictionary.json','r+') as f:
    dic = json.load(f)
    dic.update(new_dictionary)
    json.dump(dic, f)
```

(mode is `'r+'` for reading and writing, not appending because you're re-writing the entire file)

If you want to do the append thing, along with json.dumps, I guess you'd have to remove the first `{` from the json.dumps string before appending. Something like:

```
with open('python_dictionary.json','a') as f:
    str = json.dumps(new_dictionary).replace('{', ',', 1)
    f.seek(-2,2)
    f.write(str)
```

Comment: In your first example, wouldn't it be `json.dump(dic, f)`? (since `dumps` just returns a string and doesn't act on a file object)

Answer (score 1):

When the 'r+' or 'a' option does not work properly, you can do the following:

```
with open('python_dictionary.json','r') as f:
    dic = json.load(f)

dic.update(new_dictionary)

with open('python_dictionary.json','w') as f:
    json.dump(dic, f)
```

The first part read the existing dictionary. Then you update the dictionary with the new dictionary. Finally, you rewriting the whole updated dictionary.